# What is this type of old wall outlet?

Tags: outlet

We recently moved to Spain. We rented an apartment in a building which according to my estimation was erected some fifty or so years ago. There are three wall outlets (apart from a number of modern ones) in the apartment that look to me as some thing from seventies or even older. Each one of them is equipped with wire fuse. What is this standard? Was it the only type of outlets in use in Spain back then?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an Eunea Metropoli 3013-B type earthed socket.

Was mainly used in older industrial buildings for heavy duty equipment, rated for 16A. Ordinary household equipment did not use this plug.

Comment: Thank you. It is curious why they were installed, though. According to the landlady the apartment had been owned by her late parents for dozens of years. Quite ordinary apartment building, usual people... But, it is not a question to ask here, I trust.